# Como salvar o resultado de saída de um script Python para um arquivo txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Script que mostra senhas wifi salvas:

```
import subprocess
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace").split('\n')
profiles = [i.split(":") [1] [1:-1] for i in data if "Todos os Perfis de Usu\\xa0rios" in i]
for i in profiles:
    try:
        results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear']).decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace).split('\n')
        results = [b.split(":") [1] [1:-1] for b in results if "Conte\\xa3do da Chave" in b]
        try:
            print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
        except IndexError:
            print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, "")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, "ENCODING ERROR"))
input("")
```

Resultado de saída:
[image: Saída]

Como salvar o resultado de saída em um documento TXT sem precisar mostrar o PRINT no "Shell"?

Answer (score 1):

Assim como nas respostas anteriores, você pode salvar o resultado abrindo um arquivo e escrevendo a saída nele.

```
with open('nomeDoArquivo.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    # <Seu código aqui>
    print('Sua saída', file=arquivo)
```

Utilizando essa sintaxe, não é necessário fechar o arquivo após o uso, isso será feito automaticamente.

Mas também é possível modificar a saída do sistema sem modificar o seu algoritmo, através do redirecionamento da saída padrão do seu sistema operacional.

Para isso, basta executar o seguinte comando no terminal:

> python seuPrograma.py > nomeDoArquivo.txt

Seu programa funcionará da mesma forma que antes, com a diferença que a saída padrão dele agora é o arquivo "nomeDoArquivo.txt" ao invés da tela do terminal

Answer (score 0):

vc abre um arquivo com open usando a bandeira 'w', e vc pode faze uma modificação no print para mandar a informação pro arquio ao invés do terminal

```
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')
print('informação', file=arquivo) 
arquivo.close()
```

caso tenha dificuldade com a alteração do print, vc pode usar o proprio metodo de escrita do arquivo

```
arquivo.write('informação')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para escrever em um arquivo, basta o seguinte código:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'w')
file.write('Seu texto aqui')
file.close()
```

Lembrando que no código acima, o argumento `'w'` sobrescreve tudo que havia no .txt

Para adicionar arquivos sem sobrescrever o conteúdo que o .txt já possui, utilizamos o argumento ***append*** na forma:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'a')
file.write('Seu texto aqui')
file.close()
```